# Can you breed baby Dittos?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I rather need an army of Dittos of different natures, but capturing them is annoying what with their high levels and rare appearances.

Can I stick 2 Dittos in the Day Care and make new ones?

Comment: You know, you don't have to breed with Dittos to get the nature.  Ever since HeartGold/SoulSilver if either parent is holding the everstone, their child inherits that Nature [citation](http://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?p=5667076)

Comment: @tzenes I thought it was the Ditto or Female parent, but not Male non-Ditto parent.  Even so, however, an army of various-natured Dittos will come in handy for future breeding as well.

Comment: How I got my "ditto breeding army": bought Emerald version,spent 2days in the fossile maniacs cave on route 114, spent a week transfering them to Platinum->HG->Black

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Dittos cannot breed with other Dittos.

Comment: *sigh* This game is really trying to make me waste a lot of my time.

Comment: @Strix If you have a 4th gen game, it may be faster to farm a bunch from there and then just transfer them over. To recollection, the ones in D/P are pretty easy to catch and chain.

Comment: If Dittos cannot breed with other Dittos... how the hell do they propagate?

Comment: @Raven Mitosis?

Comment: @Arkive They do look a little like amoebas...

Comment: @Raven Dittos are never created or destroyed, they only change form. Thus sayeth the Law of Conversation of Ditto.